# DOJO Tree without files to display

Tags: dojo

My requirement is to create  a tree using DOJO.  With the help of some on-line tutorials I am created the tree. But now  I have to display only folders(no files). Any suggestions as how can I filter  in dojo  so that only folder can  be displayed not files inside folder.

root
  folder1
    folder2
      test.txt  --This should not be visible when users clicks on folder2.
  folder3
    test2.log   --This should not be visible when users clicks on folder3. and so on...

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is override the buildmodel of the tree you're using. So what I would do is create your own widget extending dijit/tree with the following function in there:

```
_buildModel: function() {
   var model = new ObjectStoreModel({
      store: this._store, //this can be changed to whatever store you need
      mayHaveChildren: function(item) {
         return item.type !== "folder"; //You can use whatever identifiers you need
      },
      query: {
         id: 'root'
      }
   });
 }
```

and in the buildRendering stage, you would do something like this:

```
buildRendering: function () {
   this.inherited(arguments);
   this.model = this._buildModel();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Richard !!  I will try this  approach